# mdx cross join without intersection

Tags: ssas, mdx, intersection, cross-join

I've created market basket analysis cube and I'v tried to create query that return cross join of two hierarchies ( they are identical ) and gets the results without intersection. Unfortunately I can't get correct results.

Problem:
I have 2 sets: A {a,b} and B {a,b} and I want to create new set { {a,b} } or at least { {a,b} {b,a} }

My query:

```
SELECT 
   { [Measures].[Transaction Count] }  ON COLUMNS, 
 TopCount(
    { 
                    Generate( {[Product].[Product Id].CurrentMember} as MyCellSet,
              FILTER(Existing(NonEmptyCrossJoin (
                            [Product].[Product Id].[Product Id], 
                            [Product 1].[Product Id].[Product Id]
                         )),[Product 1].[Product Id].CurrentMember.Name <> MyCellSet.CurrentMember.Name))
    },
    1000,
    [Measures].[Transaction Count]
 ) ON ROWS FROM [Market 1]
```

Do you have any idea how to redesign above query to get results that looks like cross join without intersection?

Comment: The sass (for the Sass CSS preprocessor) tag seems misused here.  Did you by chance mean sas?

Comment: @cimmanon OP probably meant for that to be [SSAS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssas).

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without intersection" ?